# UITableView or UILabel found NIL when using delegate and protocol observer method because its called before viewDidLoad

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a class named APIController where i keep all networking functions and saving responses in .plist files, and i have LogInView and HomePageView, in the loginView i call some functions when the user presses the login button, and when the user data is successfully received, the app segues to the homepage, while more functions are still running in the background with the global dispatchQueue to download more user related data,,  now in the homepage i need some sort of observer or notification when the download of data finishes so i can update the UI, I've tried protocols, but when i try to update the UI, I always get all the UI as NIL, UITableview, UITextView, everything NIL.

**after research i found that its because its called before viewDidLoad, and idea how to solve it ?**

```
class HomePageViewController:  UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

    let apiController = APIController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        apiController.homePageDelegate = self

        homeRosterTable.delegate = self
        homeRosterTable.dataSource = self
        homeRosterTable.register(UINib(nibName: "RosterCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customRosterCell")
    }
}

extension HomePageViewController: HomePageDelegate {

    func readyToLoadData() {

        apiController.loadRoster { (roaster) in
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

                self.flightList = roaster



                //   if self.nextDepFrom != nil {
                self.nextDepFrom?.text = "MOZ"
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.homeRosterTable.reloadData()
                }
                //}
            }
        }
    }
}

protocol LogInDelegate {
    func logInObserver(success: Bool, msg: String)
}
protocol HomePageDelegate {
    func readyToLoadData()
}

class APIController {

    var logInPage : LogInViewController?
    var logInDelegate : LogInDelegate?
    var homePageDelegate : HomePageDelegate?
}
```

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Double check that your outlets are hooked up properly. And make sure this isn’t getting called before `viewDidLoad` has been called. (If that’s the case, you can do `self.homeRosterTable?.reloadData()`.)

Comment: yes i did some research and now im sure its because its called before viewDidLoad

Comment: but i have no idea how can i solve it @Rob

Comment: Like I said, add that optional chaining `?` like shown above, `self.homeRosterTable?.reloadData()`.

Comment: when i do this, it never reloads @Rob

Comment: i edited my code to show you more @Rob

Comment: So where are you calling to `readyToLoadData`? This is a little strange because `readyToLoadData` is a delegate method, but you’re not initiating anything in `viewDidLoad` that would trigger the `APIController` to call `readyToLoadData`. You need to unwrap another layer of this onion for us...

Comment: i call it in a function in apiController class and that function is originally called in the previous viewController which is the loginViewController

Comment: i dont understand ur first question, but Nil message comes on this line '  self.homeRosterTable.reloadData()'

Comment: I just wanted to confirm, as the problem looks like it’s earlier in the process. I still wonder if you’ve got some `HomePageViewController()` reference lingering about somewhere or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Mahmoud, as I understand your issue is that you have declared ApiController instance in LoginViewController and as well as in HomeViewController and both objects have a different reference. You have to pass the same apiController's reference to homeViewController which is used in LoginViewController.